# NAT and UDP - IP source broadcast

Tags: networking, iptables, nat

I have a NAT issue with UDP and broadcast :

**iptables config :** (a basic port redirection same server, UDP 80 to 8080)

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

**Scenario :**

```
192.168.0.1:1234 broadcast "hello" to 192.168.0.255:80
192.168.0.2:80 receives (NAT) to port 8080
192.168.0.2:8080 answers "I'm here !" to sender (192.168.0.1:1234)
192.168.0.1:1234 get "I'm here" with the Source IP 192.168.0.255:80
```

Problem : I need the Source IP **192.168.0.2:80** instead of broadcast **192.168.0.255:80**, how could I do this ?

I already tried to POSTROUTING SNAT to change 192.168.0.255 to 192.168.0.2 but the packet doesn't enter in the table.

Comment: You're aware broadcast packets don't pass network boundaries right?

Comment: Broadcast packets can't be NATed. Use [udp-broadcast-relay](https://github.com/nomeata/udp-broadcast-relay)

Comment: udp-broadcast-relay seems nice, I will have a try tomorrow thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to various weird behaviours, I finally used **socat** to redirect ports and have no more issue (it eats more more resources but without issues)